# extract week number from date postgres

Tags: time, postgresql-9.1

I would like to extract the week number as:

```
2015-52
```

from a date formatted as:

```
2015-12-27
```

How can I perform this in postgres?

my weeks are calculated from monday to sunday.

Answer (score 95):

To get the year and the week in a single character value, use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
select to_char(current_date, 'IYYY-IW');
```

`IW` returns the year and the week number as [defined in the ISO standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) and `IYYY` returns the corresponding year (which might be the previous year).

If you need the year and the week number as numbers, use [`extract`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

```
select extract('isoyear' from current_date) as year, 
       extract('week' from current_date) as week;
```

Comment: Wow, well done on amending a 3-year old answer :) I wasn't expecting a response, just wanted to leave something for the next person to see this page 

Answer (score 6):

I have done like this

```
extract(week from cast(current_date as date))
extract(year from cast(current_date as date))
```

Comment: The expression `cast(current_date as date)` can be simplified to `current_date`

Answer (score 4):

As same with @a_horse_with_no_name, but be careful there is a little difference between `extract('isoyear' from current_date)` and `extract('year' from current_date)` if `current_date` is within week0 in new year(the last week(53) of last year), especially when you extract `week` as well.

For example:

The follow output is `2020` not `2021`

```
select EXTRACT('isoyear' from to_timestamp('2021-01-02 17:37:27', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mn:ss')) as year
```

The follow output is `2021`

```
select EXTRACT('year' from to_timestamp('2021-01-02 17:37:27', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mn:ss')) as year
```